# Tomcat 8.5 SSL Configuration Issues for .pfx

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, pfx

I need to install SSL certificate I have received in the form of .pfx file and password.
I tried configuring the connectors as below:

```
<Connector
           
           port="8888" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576"
        compression="on" 
        compressionMinSize="1024" 
         protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json" 
           relaxedQueryChars='[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;'
        hostName = "abc.123.com">
           <SSLHostConfig hostName="abc.123.com" protocols="TLSv1.2,+TLSv1.1,+TLSv1">
            <Certificate  certificateKeystoreFile="conf/abc.123.com.pfx"
                 certificateKeystorePassword="12345"
                    type="RSA"
                        
                         />
        </SSLHostConfig> 
       
 
        </Connector>
```

However, I am getting the below error and I am not able to understand what is the issue here:

28-Apr-2023 11:56:53.656 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8888"]
28-Apr-2023 11:56:53.835 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8888]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:848)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:100)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:72)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1118)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:224)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:331)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:98)
... 20 more